# How disable Bluetooth automatically when there is no active connection anymore after a while?

Tags: bluetooth, connection

I'm looking for a solution to keep Bluetooth disabled if there is some idle or no active connections after a while.

Let's say after 10 min.

Is there some exist one?

The purpose of that, to save battery power on an unplugged laptop.

Comment: One poster found the power consumption is quite minimal; 2.8 mW at idle. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2535/will-constantly-having-bluetooth-on-drain-my-battery-too-fast Reducing screen brightness slightly would cover that handily.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2758967/a-bluetooth-mouse-or-keyboard-fails-to-reconnect-after-being-left-idle By default your computer probably already can turn off the Bluetooth device to save power when necessary.

Comment: @music2myear, yeah, forgot about it. It can be a question. Thanks for pointing at.

Comment: @K7AAY, yeah, it's definitely good to know. Thank you!